# Función wp_mail no envía correo

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Tengo un problema al crear una plantilla personalizada de formulario de contacto. Hago todos los códigos, los cuales mostraré pero al momento de probarla, aun cuando aparentemente sale bien, no llega el correo a la dirección señalada en el código. Necesito saber cual es el error, por el cual no me llega el correo.

```html
//este es el archivo page-contacto.php
<?php get_header(); ?>
<head>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="wrap">
 <h1>Formulario de Inscripción</h1>
 <?php if(isset($_GET['errormsg'])): ?>
 <div style="background-color: lightcoral; color: red; padding: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;">
  
  <p style="margin=0;"><?php echo $_GET['errormsg']; ?></p>
 </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php if(isset($_GET['exito'])): ?>
 <div style="background-color: lightgreen; color: green; padding: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;">
  
  <p style="margin=0;">Su email ha sido enviado</p>
 </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ));?>" method="post">
  <div class="row">
 
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Nombre <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" required ></label>
    <label>Apellido <input type="text" name="apellido" value="" required ></label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Edad <input type="number" name="edad" value="" min="18" required></label>
   </div>
 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
 
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Nacionalidad <input type="text" name="nacionalidad" value="" required ></label>
    <label>Número de Pasaporte <input type="text" name="pasaporte" value="" required ></label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Sexo: </p>
         <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="masculino" id="masculino" /> <label for="masculino">Masculino</label><br />
         <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="femenino" id="femenino" /> <label for="femenino">Femenino</label><br />
   </div>
 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Lugar de Emisión de Pasaporte: <input type="text" name="lugar" value="" required ></label>
    
    <label>E-mail <input type="email" name="correo" value="" required ></label>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <label> Fecha de Expiración <input type="date" name="expira" value="expira" id="expira"></label>
      <label> Fecha de Emisión <input type="date" name="emision" value="emision" id="emision"></label>
   </div>
   
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Por favor, haga un upload de su pasaporte en un archivo .jpg</p>
      <label><input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg" name="photopass" id="photopass"></label>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Indique si desea recibir newsletters de nosotros:</p>
      <input type="radio" name="news" value="si" id="si" /> <label for="si">Si</label><br />
     <input type="radio" name="news" value="no" id="no" /> <label for="no">No</label><br />

      
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Teléfono en Caso de Emergencia <input type="tel" name="teler" id="teler"></label>
      <label>Teléfono <input type="tel" name="telefono" id="telefono"></label>
   </div>
   <!-- Agregado luego para prueba de envio -->
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactform">
   </div>
   <!-- fin agregado -->
  </div>

 </form>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

```html
//este es el archivo formulario.php
<?php 
function captura_de_valores(){
 //Verificar campos Obligatorios y campos válidos
 if ( !isset($_POST['nombre']) || empty($_POST['nombre']) ):
  wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array('errormsg' => 'error' ), get_home_url() . "/contacto" ) ); exit;
 endif;
 //sanitizar los valores
 $nombre = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['nombre'] );
 $apellido = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['apellido'] );
 $edad = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['edad'] );
 $nacionalidad = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['nacionalidad'] );
 $pasaporte = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pasaporte'] );
 $sexo = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['sexo'] );
 $lugar = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['lugar'] );
 $expira = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['expira'] );
 $emision = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['emision'] );
 $email = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email'] );
 $photopass = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['photopass'] );
 $news = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['news'] );
 $teler = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['teler'] );
 $telefono = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['telefono'] );

 //enviar email
 wp_mail("jpgotopo@gmail.com", "Formulario de contacto", "El usuario " . $nombre . " envió este mensaje => " . $apellido  );
 //Redirigir a mensaje de exito

 wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array('exito' => '1' ), get_home_url() . "/contacto" ) ); exit;

}

add_action('admin_post_nopriv_contactform', 'captura_de_valores');
add_action('admin_post_contactform', 'captura_de_valores');
?>
```

```html
//en functions.php agrego esta linea de codigo. 
<?php 
function captura_de_valores(){
 //Verificar campos Obligatorios y campos válidos
 if ( !isset($_POST['nombre']) || empty($_POST['nombre']) ):
  wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array('errormsg' => 'error' ), get_home_url() . "/contacto" ) ); exit;
 endif;
 //sanitizar los valores
 $nombre = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['nombre'] );
 $apellido = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['apellido'] );
 $edad = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['edad'] );
 $nacionalidad = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['nacionalidad'] );
 $pasaporte = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pasaporte'] );
 $sexo = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['sexo'] );
 $lugar = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['lugar'] );
 $expira = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['expira'] );
 $emision = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['emision'] );
 $email = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email'] );
 $photopass = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['photopass'] );
 $news = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['news'] );
 $teler = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['teler'] );
 $telefono = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['telefono'] );

 //enviar email
 wp_mail("jpgotopo@gmail.com", "Formulario de contacto", "El usuario " . $nombre . " envió este mensaje => " . $apellido  );
 //Redirigir a mensaje de exito

 wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array('exito' => '1' ), get_home_url() . "/contacto" ) ); exit;

}

add_action('admin_post_nopriv_contactform', 'captura_de_valores');
add_action('admin_post_contactform', 'captura_de_valores');
?>
```

Comment: Incluye una captura de error para ver qué es lo que ocurre: `add_action( 'wp_mail_failed', 'onMailError', 10, 1 );
function onMailError( $wp_error ) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wp_error);
    echo "</pre>";
}` ¿Seguro que los datos del POST no están vacíos?

Comment: No sale mensaje de error. De hecho como veras en el codigo, hay redireccion en caso tal que haya éxito en el envío tambien hay redireccion si sale error, cuando ejecuto me sale el mensaje de exito.

Comment: ¿El emal `jpgotopo@gmail.com` es tuyo? ¿Revisaste en la carpeta de spam? Si no es tu correo, cámbialo por un correo tuyo y revisa si no está llegando a la carpeta de spam.

Comment: el correo es mio, he revisado hasta donde más no se puede.

Comment: @A.Cedano por favor padre, si ve alguna falla me avisa.

Comment: No veo ningún fallo, `wp_mail` es muy simple, los parámetros están bien. ¿Revisaste la carpeta spam?  Prueba con la función `mail` de PHP. Pon un echo en alguna parte del código para ver si está entrando en ese bloque. No se me ocurre qué pueda estar fallando. Revisa el log de errores o activa temporalmente el modo debug para ver si te muestra algún mensaje de error específico.

Comment: @A.Cedano  No tendrá que ver que lo estoy haciendo en XAMPP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mis problemas en este sentido los resolvi instalando y configurando [WP Mail SMTP](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

No basta con tener un plugin de formularios, sino que además el servidor debe permitir la función php **mail()** que no suele estar disponible por seguridad (supongo) ya que es más seguro por SMTP.

Si tienes alguna duda de como utilizar el plugin, vuelve por aquí y te ayudo.